# Need to run the download when the application run in background

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I have downloaded 300 images in my application and store it in isolated storage using http request from a server.The problem we are facing is when navigate out form the application by pressing windows button or anyother way. the download stops.We need to run the download continously without errors even the application goes background. kindly guide me

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Background File Transfer API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202955%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). It allows you to queue up one or more file uploads or downloads over HTTP that will be executed in the background, even when the application is no longer running in the foreground.

Comment: how to open a file once it has been downloaded by the Background File Transfer API?? suppose I download a pdf, how to open it in the pdf viewer?

Comment: files are saved to the isolated storage, so you open it the same way you would open any other file from there. There is currently no way you can open a downloaded PDF in a PDF viewer. The only way is to make a WebBrowserTask navigate to the PDF url

Comment: so if i have a file on dropbox which is public so that i can retrieve it via a link. Will I be able to download it using this API? Can you guide me by providing some tutorial links?